# how to change python version used by apache?

Tags: python, html, apache, path, cgi

When I launch my CGI (common gateway interface) by using this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import cgi
import os
import json 
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

print 'Content-type: text/html'

print


print '<html><head><title>Interface Ticket Recognition</title></head><body>'

formulaire = cgi.FieldStorage()



os.chdir("C:\Users\iyacine\Desktop")

path= os.getcwd()

from subprocess import call
call(["Python", "applicationV1.py"])

if path=="C:\Users\iyacine\Desktop":
    print '''changer'''

print '</body></html>'
```

I got an error:

[image]

I try to change the path in environment variable but this work only in cmd.

I installed anaconda i my computer and i can run the module sklearn.feature_extraction.text in Spyder but not from Apache. Do you know how to solve this issue please?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: for better readability please edit your question and mark your code as code (the `{ }` button)

Answer (score 0):

You should have a first line like `#! /usr/bin/python` (called Shebang line) in your script. You have to change that line to point to the python executable you actually want. For Windows have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html?highlight=shebang#shebang-lines) but there also is the possibility to run ".bat" files via CGI so you could use a file (eg `runmyscript.bat`) containing just

```
@C:\path\to\anaconda\python.exe path\to\script.py
```

which is a hacky workaround (I think) but should work, too.

In my experience it is the best to use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) if possible - this does not fix the path-problem directly but helps keeping different applications isolated.